# LuaTeX: Glyph property table doesn't get copied upon vbox copy

Tags: luatex, box, luahbtex, property-list

When I copy a vbox, its glyph's property table isn't copied. Is there a way to make it work? The property table might sound uninteresting for Node renderer,[*] but is quite valuable (for its `glyph_info` property) when rendered with HarfBuzz renderer.

[*] *As a bonus, please let me know what does property `state=num` mean when `Renderer=Node`.*

Test code, and screenshots are below (please read comments in code to see how to run it):

```latex
% >> lualatex glyphprops.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Renderer=HarfBuzz,Script=Latin]{Linux Libertine O}
% ctan version of package nodetree gives lua error on HarfBuzz, use Node instead if you don't have latest github version
%\setmainfont[Renderer=Node,Script=Latin]{Linux Libertine O}

\usepackage[callback={}]{nodetree}

\begin{document}

    \NodetreeRegisterCallback{vpack_filter}

    \setbox0=\vbox{{\hsize=2in\relax Hello world\endgraf}}

    % NOTE: Comment following for second run
    \box0

    % NOTE: Uncomment following for second run
    %\copy0

    \newpage\null

    \NodetreeUnregisterCallback{vpack_filter}

\end{document}
```

Glyphs properties are not copied with `\copy0`:

[image: vbox copy yields empty properties]

Glyphs properties are copied? to main vertical list with `\box0`:

[image: vbox properties available in original vbox]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr: They already are accessible, just try actually reading it in Lua code.

As documented in the LuaTeX manual, there are two options how to handle properties when copying nodes with property tables: You can either share the property table or give the new copy a new table which uses the metatable to "inherit" the values from the old table. (LuaTeX manual, section 8.11) If luaotfload is loaded (aka. always in LuaLaTeX) the metatable mode is chosen. (DO NOT CHANGE THIS! THINGS *WILL* BREAK)

Therefore all entries from the metatable of the original node are available, but they are not listed when iterating over the keys of the table (as done in nodetree).

About the `state` property: It is an implementation detail which will change and should never be relied upon. While it is currently implemented as a property in LuaLaTeX, the precise storage location tends to change every now and then. (Iff you really want to access it, use `luaotfload.fontloader.nodes.nuts.getstate`. The values identify glyph types for various features, a mapping can be found in `luaotfload.fontloader.fonts.analyzers.states`)

Comment: When I add a directlua block with `last_tail = tex.nest.top.tail` right under the command `\box0` or `\copy0`, and try to print any information about it, I get that its a `temp node (id 41)`, so it's not useful... Why does the `tex.nest.top.tail` recipe doesn't work here? Is there something missing? Is there a more generic recipe to query last node?

Comment: @reportaman The box node is in the main vertical list. As known from \lastbox and friends, the last node can't reliably be queried from the main vertical list (especially since it may already be deleted if the output routine ran in the meantime). In cases like this where the node is still there, it will often already be moved to the current page. You can find it with `node.tail(tex.lists.page_head)`.

Comment: Thanks Marcel, so is it correct to assume that `tex.nest.top.tail` is safe to use in places other than main vertical list? Like inside a vbox? Also, whats the source of this knowledge: "As known from \lastbox and friends, the last node can't reliably be queried from the main vertical list" Is it mentioned somewhere (like section of a book) while discussing main vertical list, or is it based on your own observation of tex's behavior (its output routine)?

Comment: @reportaman It should be safe everywhere else, but the last node might not always be the one you expect. The restriction of \lastbox in the main vertical list is e.g. documented in the TeXbook (search for the description of \lastbox).

Comment: Thanks, that worked! and I was able to access property table of nodes in `\copy0`